# How to call service methods of spring boot using javascript variables in Thymeleaf Template

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Iam taking selected options as a category(ex-Business category) and iam passing it to the javascript function.From that category value iam getting all data Id's(Ex-sales data), This id's I need to pass it to the service class methods to get the Particular sales data

``

```
    $(function () {
        $("#configMessageTypeDrop").change(function () {
            if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
                $(this).data('options', $('#message option').clone());
            }       
            var id =$(this).val();
            $("textarea#message").val([[${@smsTemplateDetailsServiceImpl.findOneSmsTemplateDetails(id).getSmsTemplateMessage()}]]);

        })``
```

id iam passing it to the 
`[[${@smsTemplateDetailsServiceImpl.findOneSmsTemplateDetails(id).getSmsTemplateMessage()}]]`
It's showing that id is null,But I need to use that id to call service method.